Does $x$ and $(\nabla f)(x)$ align as we approach the minima for a convex function?
Given a convex function $f(x): \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, let $h(x)$ denote the cosine of the angle between $x$ and $(\nabla f)(x)$.
$$h(x) := \frac{x^\top.(\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert x\Vert \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}$$
It appears intuitively that $|h(x)|$ should be maximized if we move towards the minima.
$$\lim_{x \to x^*} |h(x)| = 1$$
I couldn't find a 1D or 2D example that violates this idea. Can we prove it?
Edit
Consider gradient descent (GD) on $f(x)$. Is the hypothesis that $h$ never increases as long as we don't overshoot the minima correct?
The change $\delta h$ to the first order due to GD can be written as
$$\delta h \approx -\eta (\nabla f)(x)^\top (\nabla h)(x)$$
where $\eta$ is the learning rate. Assuming we never overshoot the minima, does $\delta h \leq 0$ along the GD path?
Efforts so far
Differentiating $h(x)$, we have
$$(\nabla h)(x)^\top = \frac{x^\top}{\Vert x \Vert \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}\left(I - \frac{(\nabla f)(x) (\nabla f)(x)^\top}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^2}\right)H + \frac{(\nabla f)(x)^\top}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert \Vert x \Vert}\left(I - \frac{x x^\top}{\Vert x \Vert^2}\right)$$
where $H$ is the Hessian. Post-multiplying this by $(\nabla f)(x)$, we have:
\begin{aligned}
(\nabla h)(x)^\top (\nabla f)(x) &\approx \frac{x^\top}{\Vert x \Vert \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}\left(I - \frac{(\nabla f)(x) (\nabla f)(x)^\top}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^2}\right) H(\nabla f)(x) + \\ &\frac{(\nabla f)(x)^\top}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert \Vert x \Vert}\left((\nabla f)(x) - \frac{x x^\top (\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert x \Vert^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{x^\top H (\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert x \Vert \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert} - \frac{x^\top (\nabla f)(x) (\nabla f)(x)^\top H(\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert x\Vert \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^3} + \\
&\frac{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} - \frac{(\nabla f)(x)^\top x x^\top (\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert \Vert x \Vert^3} \\
&= \frac{x^\top H (\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert x \Vert \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert} - \frac{(\nabla f)(x)^\top H(\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^2} h(x) + \\
&\frac{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} - \frac{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} (h(x))^2 \\
\end{aligned}
Multiplying by $-\eta$, we recover $\delta h$ as
\begin{aligned}
\delta h &\approx -\eta \frac{x^\top H (\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert x \Vert \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert} + \eta \frac{(\nabla f)(x)^\top H(\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^2} h(x) - \\
&\eta \frac{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} + \eta \frac{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} (h(x))^2 \\
&= \eta \left(\frac{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} (h(x))^2 + \frac{(\nabla f)(x)^\top H(\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^2} h(x) - \\ \left[\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert + \frac{x^\top H (\nabla f)(x)}{\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert}\right] \frac1{\Vert x \Vert} \right)
\end{aligned}
This is a quadratic expression in $h(x)$. Factorizing we have,
\begin{aligned}
\delta h &\approx \eta \left[\left(h(x) + \frac{\Vert x \Vert (\nabla f)(x)^\top H(\nabla f)(x) + \lambda}{2 \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^3}\right) \\
\left(h(x) + \frac{\Vert x \Vert (\nabla f)(x)^\top H(\nabla f)(x) - \lambda}{2 \Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^3}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
where $\lambda = \sqrt{\Vert x \Vert^2 ((\nabla f)(x)^\top H(\nabla f)(x))^2 + 4\Vert (\nabla f)(x) \Vert^4 \left[\Vert (\nabla f)(x)\Vert^2 + x^\top H (\nabla f)(x)\right]}$.
This is where I am hitting a wall. Given that $-1 \leq h(x) \leq 1$ by definition, how to proceed further? Is this the correct direction?
PS:
Apologies for the long edit. I figured that the edit could potentially be a different question altogether, so I asked another question. However, it keeps getting suggested as a duplicate of this one, despite me making attempts to explain how it is not. If that is true, this edit is not so different from the original after all and, hence, deserves updated answers.

In dimension $1$ the "angle" (actually the cosine) is always $\pm1$ outside the singular points and the origin, and the question becomes a bit meaningless.
In higher dimensions it is $\pm1$ iff the contour hypersurface through $x$ is parallel to the sphere through $x$ and centered at the origin, and $0$ iff that hypersurface intersects that sphere orthogonally. An isolated minimum of $f$ different from the origin will have arbitrarily small contour hypersurfaces in its neighbourhood, and therefore there will be $x$ where $h(x)=1$ arbitrarily close to that minimum, but for the same reason there will be $x$ with $h(x)=0$ arbitrarily close to it, i.e., the function $h$ does not have a continuous extension at the minimum.
As an example consider $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+y^2.$ The cosine is $-1$ on the open line segment between the origin and $(1,0);$ and it is $0$ on the circle centered at $(1/2,0)$ with radius $1/2$ (minus the two points on the circumference where $h$ is not defined).

I do not know what the flowlines of gradient descent look like for a general convex function. If they are more or less well-behaved near the minimum then the function $h$ could have a directional limit. In my example the flowline is a straight line from the starting point to the minimum. Along that flowline the function $h$ has a directional limit that is equal to the (cosine of the) angle between that flowline and the $X$ axis. For example, coming from the vertical half line above the minimum, it would decrease to $0.$ Coming from the right or the left along the $X$ axis it would be constant.
